# Generated WSDL has nillable="true" for @RequestWrapper

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

**My question is**: How can I setup the CXF system so that the service method signature is the same as the client signature? Even when using @RequestWrapper? 
Also see the question beeing asked two years ago: [old question](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cxf-users/201305.mbox/%3C5FA1A421460E2D4EB0B1129D498A5D4F353CC1C3@W12112.ldschurch.org%3E)

When using the @RequestWrapper on my @WebMethod this results in nillable="true" in the generated WSDL.
From this WSDL I generate java with Maven (cxf-codegen-plugin) and when nillable is set the arguments of the method are wrapped.

```
@WebMethod(action = "getAvailableMoments")
@RequestWrapper(className = "webservice.wrappers.GetAvailableMomentsWrapper")
public List<Moment> getAvailableMoments(LocalDate selectedDate) {
}
```

The wrapper looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class GetAvailableMomentsWrapper implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class, type = LocalDate.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    private LocalDate selectedDate;
}
```

Then part of the wsdl looks like this:

```
...
<xs:element name="getAvailableMoments" nillable="true" type="tns:getAvailableMomentsWrapper"/>
...
```

And then the generated java code looks like this:

```
@WebMethod(action = "getAvailableMoments")
@SOAPBinding(parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.BARE)
@WebResult(name = "getAvailableMomentsResponse", targetNamespace = "calendar.service.vetsware.nl", partName = "parameters")
public GetAvailableMomentsResponse getAvailableMoments(
    @WebParam(partName = "parameters", name = "getAvailableMoments", targetNamespace = "calendar.service.vetsware.nl")
    GetAvailableMomentsWrapper parameters
);
```

But when I set nillable="false", then java code looks like I would like to have:

```
@WebMethod(action = "getAvailableMoments")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "getAvailableMoments", targetNamespace = "calendar.service.vetsware.nl", className = "nl.vetsware.service.calendar.GetAvailableMomentsWrapper")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "getAvailableMomentsResponse", targetNamespace = "calendar.service.vetsware.nl", className = "nl.vetsware.service.calendar.GetAvailableMomentsResponse")
@WebResult(name = "return", targetNamespace = "")
public java.util.List<nl.vetsware.service.calendar.Moment> getAvailableMoments(
    @WebParam(name = "selectedDate", targetNamespace = "")
    java.time.LocalDate selectedDate
);
```

Comment: I added the 'com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin' to my pom and in phase 'initialize' I remove 'nillable="true"' from the wsdl. Big ugly hack but it seems to do the job.

Comment: Still would like to know how this should be done